# different fonts for arabtex package

Tags: fonts, arabtex

I would like to change the font which is used in arabtex package

```
 \documentclass[30pt,oneside,a4paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}       
 \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
 \usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}  %%LAE to avoid el5at el 3arabi el morakab
 \usepackage{arabtex} 
 \usepackage{cp1256,utf8}
  \setcode{utf8}

 \begin{document}

\<مخ يمين>
\end{document}
```

The output of this font is not easy for kids to read, as the letters are written so integrated with eachother

i would like to switch to a more simplified font like

مـخ يـمـيـن

is there any tipp

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the `arabtex` manual, section `3.3 Font selection`:

> For producing the extended Arabic script ArabTeX uses a special strategy to build up character shapes from a collection of fragments, which normally do not correspond to individual character glyphs. Therefore none of the available free or commercial Arabic fonts can be used; we provide our own pseudo-fonts.

Is it an option to switch to the `polyglossia` package and `xelatex` as the compiler?

[image]

```
\documentclass[30pt,oneside,a4paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont
  [Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits,Ligatures=TeX]{Simplified Arabic.ttf}
\begin{document}
مخ يمين
\end{document}
```

Compile with `xelatex`. I think I downloaded the font from https://fontzone.net/font-details/simplified-arabic . Under Windows, it may be necessary to remove the extension, i.e., try `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[...]{Simplified Arabic}` (without `ttf`).

Comment: Thanks, that would help

I would also appretiate if i can keep using the package arabtex and to compile using pdflatex, as changing that will affect some other parts in the document such as the tables and so on.